# What is the magic behind that recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

**Question:**

Can you explain me how that fuction returns the correct result `16`?
I am new to programming and now this code is recursive, however I think I am getting lost as much as I think I understand them. Even though, I believe I figure out factorial recursions or fibonacci ones.

The base is `0`, that's good, but I can't figure out why I get `16`...
 I printed every variable inside the function and dubugged, but those did not help more than troubling. When `b` variable is `0` (and `a` variable is `32`) the condition is met, but why it returns value `16`? I would understand a kind of function as `n * fact(n-1)` as in a classic factorial fuction example, but here I can't visualize how the recursion returns the expected result.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
int fun(int a, int b)  
{ 
   if (b == 0) 
    {
       return 0; 
    }
   if (b % 2 == 0) 
    {
    return fun(a+a, b/2);
    }
   return fun(a+a, b/2)+a;
} 
  
int main() 
{ 
  printf("%d\n", fun(4, 4)); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a great opportunity to learn how to use your debugger. With the debugger you can step through your code and examine the contents of variables. While stepping though your code, you'll understand how recursion works here. If you're too lazy to learn how to use the debugger, you can put appropriate `printf`s in your code.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: But debugging recursive functions may be tricky. For a simple case such as this, I would recommend running the code by hand (& pen & paper). Just don't forget that `+ a;` in the last line!

Comment: You think so? All Cs50 ide shows me how the numbers increment but not what i expected to understand. Is there any kind of function that i dont see which calculates, say, an incremention like 4 + 4+ 4 +4 or a math magic?

Comment: If you check your variables, you will see that it does not go `4, 8, 12, 16, ...` but `4, 8, 16, 32`.

Comment: @SerhatAkbak You could use gdb, or a interface for it like cgdb, and use the backtrace command to see the current backtrace.

Comment: @SerhatAkbak If it is from CS50, there's a `CS50` tag you can add to the question

Comment: @AbhayAravinda not. It is a random c exercise thati encountered today. This has cofused me so much, give that cs50 has not done that enough for couple of days!

Comment: In order to understand recursion, you first need to understand recursion. On a serious note, students spend _way_ too much time scratching their heads while viewing artificial recursion examples. Most of the time recursion is just plain bad coding and should almost never be used in real world programs. It can make sense to look at it as part of algorithm theory class, but never as part of a beginner C class. Beginners should _never_ use recursion.

Comment: @Lundin i have the same opinion with you on recursions for beginners but the internet tells how important and powerful recursion is! they make you think it is a must and cant go beyond without understanding it

Comment: @SerhatAkbak Yes, persistent myths enforced by teachers is a huge problem for the software industry. Similar problematic myths are "goto considered harmful" and "dynamic 2D arrays are always allocated with `type**`". There are valid cases for all of these (even recursion), but they are special corner cases and somewhat advanced topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add printouts and it will become very clear:

```
int fun(int a, int b)
{
    printf("fun(%d, %d)\n", a, b);
    if (b == 0) {
         printf("b == 0, returning 0\n");
         return 0;
    }
    if (b % 2 == 0) {
        printf("b is even, returning f(%d, %d)\n", a+a, b/2);
        return fun(a+a, b/2);
    }
    printf("b is odd, returning f(%d, %d) + %d\n", a+a, b/2, a);
    return fun(a+a, b/2)+a;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
fun(4, 4)
b is even, returning f(8, 2)
fun(8, 2)
b is even, returning f(16, 1)
fun(16, 1)
b is odd, returning f(32, 0) + 16
fun(32, 0)
b == 0, returning 0
16
```

So what happens in the end is that `f(16, 1)` will return `f(32, 0) + 16` and `f(32, 0)` evaluates to zero, so `16` is returned.

You could also do like this, but do note that this will alter the order of the outputs because the printout need to wait for the return:

```
int fun(int a, int b)  
{ 
    printf("fun(%d, %d)\n", a, b);
    if (b == 0) {
        printf("b == 0, returning 0\n");
        return 0; 
    }
    if (b % 2 == 0) {
        int ret = fun(a+a, b/2);
        printf("b is even, returning f(%d, %d) = %d \n", a+a, b/2, ret); 
        return ret; //fun(a+a, b/2);
    }
    int ret = fun(a+a, b/2) + a;
    printf("b is odd, returning f(%d, %d) + %d = %d \n", a+a, b/2, a, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
fun(4, 4)
fun(8, 2)
fun(16, 1)
fun(32, 0)
b == 0, returning 0
b is odd, returning f(32, 0) + 16 = 16 
b is even, returning f(16, 1) = 16 
b is even, returning f(8, 2) = 16 
16
```

A good way to understand recursion is to use pen and paper to see why the order of printouts is so different in these cases. But I leave that to you.

Comment: thank you. I did not print it that way. it helped much. i think the trick is on variable `a`

Answer (score 0):

I find helpful to think about these kind of recursive functions as mathematical tools. What I mean is that a recursive function works if:

- It always says the truth.
- You can prove that it ends, eventually.

You don't say, but I guess that your function `fun(a, b)` does a multiplication `a * b`. And it does it by reducing it:

- If `b==0` then `a * b -> 0`
- Else, if `b is even` then `a * b -> (a+a) * (b/2)`.
- Else (`b is odd`), `a * b -> ((a+a) * (b/2)) + a`

These equations are trivially true, as long as `b >= 0` of course, which I assume that is a precondition of your function.

You also can see that it will eventually finish, as the value of `b` gets smaller and smaller, and it will always reach 0 at the end.

That should be enough to believe that your function works. If you want to trace each intermediate step, you can check your truth every time to ensure that you doing it properly.

- `a=4, b=4`, `b` is even, so `foo(4,4) -> foo(8, 2)` (we know that `4*4 == 16`, and `8*2 == 16` too, so we are on the right track).
- `a=8, b=2`, `b` is even, so `foo(8, 2) -> foo(16, 1)` (`16 * 1 ==16`, we are still ok).
- `a=16, b=1`, `b` is odd, so `foo(16, 1) -> foo(32, 0) + 16`. Here is the tricky part, this call is not tail-recursive, there is the latter addition. But still, `32*0 + 16 = 16` so we are on the right track.
- `a=32, b=0` `b` is 0 so it returns `0` (ok, because `32*0 = 0`).
- Then there is the latter sum: `0 + 16 = 16` and that value is returned all up to `main`.

Comment: you say "You don't say, but I guess that your function fun(a, b) does a multiplication a * b. And it does it by reducing it." but i dont see such a multiplication as you told me. All i see is "a + a" colculation which continues till `b` reached 0, but is not all i did here just a incremention of a variables? I mean, in other examples i can clearly see any multiplication or division but here it is not even vague it is non existent to my eyes. Is there any such rule as if you put two variable inside a recursive function it does multiplications or anything else?

Comment: It felt like that duck method. the more i try to explain my situation the more i get it. I think all i get here is a variable which is loaded 16 at the end of the condition, but changing status of  a and b somehow multiplied each other. that is still a big questions!

Comment: @SerhatAkbak: A multiplication is just a repeated sum `4 * 4` is defined mathematically as `4+4+4+4`. And your recursive function goes from `4 * 4` to `(4+4) * 2`, then to `((4+4)+(4+4)) * 1`, finally to `0 + ((4+4)+(4+4))`.

Comment: I know basic math and its principles but here in this function i cant see multiplication action. That was the problem if mine but anyway thanks again you helped me out a lot to grasp at least a bit of it. Best!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things about recursive functions:

1. recursive functions are not special. Eg. they work the same way as if you called a different function that served the same purpose for the smaller sub problems.
2. All functions will have their own arguments and local variables. The location of `a` and `b` is new for each invocation of a fucntion. Thus if you call the same function from itself **there will be no interference between the two!**

You should do substitution rules:

1. Replace the call with the code that is executed according to the conditionals.
2. Repeat until you no longer have anything to call

Example:

```
fun(4, 4)            // initial call 
fun(4+4, 4/2)        // because 4 % 2 == 0 
fun(8+8, 2/2)        // because 2 % 2 == 0
fun(16+16, 1/2) + 16 // because 1 % 2 != 0. 
0 + 16               // because 1/2 == 0 and then b == 0
16                   // because 0 + 16 == 16
```

Comment: I see now. I have overlooked the return value 0 in the first condition. Since b is 0 then return of the last function is zero so it returns 0 + 16 which is the last action before the condition met. Thank you and @rodrigo, it has nt been untill decomposing each part of the function that i understand it. now it is a little bit fun!